# Rename [sybase-ase] and [sybase-iq]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

SAP has bought up Sybase and is now in the process of renaming everything Sybase to SAP, see [here for ASE](https://www.sap.com/product/data-mgmt/sybase-ase.html) and [here for IQ](https://www.sap.com/product/data-mgmt/sybase-iq-big-data-management.html).

Should we rename the tags [sybase-ase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase-ase) and [sybase-iq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase-iq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rename is now done; the primary tags are [sap-ase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-ase) and [sap-iq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-iq).

The [sap-ase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-ase) tag had been created in the meantime, but only had a small number of questions to its name. I've merged the [sybase-ase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase-ase) into it and created a synonym mapping.

For [sap-iq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-iq), I just renamed the old [sybase-iq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase-iq) tag, and created a synonym mapping to the old tag name. I also updated the tag wiki excerpt to add a note of the old name.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I thought this was lost and forgotten.

Comment: In all honesty, it *was*... We have a pretty long backlog for tag requests, but occasionally time permits going through the old requests and handling some of the ones that slipped through the cracks.